# Swift capture input values in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a few different UITableViewCells and at the minute it don't do anything. I've added a method to my class to try and get the data but I don't know how to store it.

How can I put all the values from the view cells into some sort of array?

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    fieldValues.append(textField.text!)
    print(textField)
}
```

I've got this method but it's just going to keep adding the values to the array. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Is there a textfield within each cell?
> "I've added a method to my class to try and get the data but I don't know how to store it." To which class did you added this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can create dictionary and store values for index path keys:

```
var storage = [NSIndexPath: String]()
storage[NSIndexPathForYouTextField] = textField.text
```

Comment: Yea thats what I was thinking but how do I get an index?

Comment: You can create subclass of `UITextField` and add `indexPath` property, than set it up when you construct you cells.

Comment: Ok cool, i've added a class called `IndexTextField` and i've changed my method to `textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: IndexTextField)` but now it's saying about a conflict with uitextfielddeligate

Comment: No need to change method. All delegate calls must works as usual, you need to do: `if let indexedTextField = textField as IndexTextFiled { use index }`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, specify a universal tag in the cell for the textfield for which you want to get the value.

Secondly make a method to fetch all the inputs made in all the  textfields of uitableview, like this:-

```
for i in 0...tableView.numberOfSections-1
{
    for j in 0...tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(i)-1
    {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: j, inSection: i)) 
           {
                  fieldValues.append((cell.contentView.viewWithTag(999) as UITextField).text!)

            }

    }
}
```